# jquery using reference variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

My referenced vars keep getting reset to 0, why? Each section has a set of Previous and Next buttons, initially they work fine but when I return to a section the counter for that section is set to 0. It should retain the number it had been set to previously. Thanks in advance. This is not the actual code being used, but it demonstrates the issue ( I hope )

```
var currentPageIndex = null;
var section1_count = 0;
var section2_count = 0;
var section3_count = 0;

function checkSectionPage( value ){
    switch(value){
        case "section1":
            currentPageIndex= section1_count;
            break;
        case "section2":
            currentPageIndex= section2_count;
            break;
        case "section3":
            currentPageIndex= section3_count;
            break;
    }
}
$('.slidePrevious').click(function(){
    checkSectionPage($(this).parent().attr('id'));
    currentPageIndex--;
});
$('.slideNext').click(function(){
    checkSectionPage($(this).parent().attr('id'));
    currentPageIndex++;
});
```

Comment: because you never update section count. It is always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update section#_count. When you set `currentPageIndex` to the section, the section number does not just increase. You would need to manually update it.

Do something like this:

```
var activeSection = "section1";
var sects = {
    "section1" : 0,
    "section2" : 0,
    "section3" : 0
};

$('.slidePrevious').click(function(){
    sects[$(this).parent().attr('id')]--;
});
$('.slideNext').click(function(){
    sects[$(this).parent().attr('id')]--;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies and solutions. Most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing/decrementing what you think you are.
You want something like:

```
currentPageIndex = "section1_count";
 ...

window[currentPageIndex]++;
```

*(bare vars, "global variables", in a browser context are actually fields in the `window` object)*

Or to move your counts into an object (like @pascarello's answer) or perhaps into an array, along these lines:

```
var pageIndexes = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

which = 1;
 ...

pageIndexes[which]++;
```